# Check whether all attached methods were successfully completed

Tags: c#, silverlight, events, xaml

I'm developing a Silverlight LOB application. 
Due to some required functionality I've created a new NewBasePage class for all pages. This class is derived from the Page class. I've added couple events and raise them manually.

But I'm stuck with some stuff. I need to check  whether all methods that are bound to some event were successfully completed. Is there any way to do this?

New Base Class:

```
public class NewPageBase : Page
{
        public void RefreshData(Action resultAction = null)
        {
            if (StartRefreshingData != null) StartRefreshingData(this, null);

            if (resultAction != null) resultAction();
        }

        public event EventHandler StartRefreshingData;

}
```

Xaml:

```
<newbase:NewBasePage ...>

...

  <i:Interraction.Triggers>
    <i:EventTrigger EventName="StartRefreshingData">
        <i:InvokeCommandAction Command="{StaticResource someCommandFromViewModel}"/>
    </i:EventTrigger>
  </i:Interraction.Triggers>
</newbase:NewBasePage>
```

Comment: As far as I know events are called synchronously, which means, when the code after raising the event is called, the execution of all attached event handlers is finished (which obviously doesn't include threads started by them).

Comment: Tobias is right, events are run synchronously. What are you trying to accomplish by knowing that the event handlers completed successfully?

Comment: @M.Babcock I'm raising `OnPageChanging` event, and if any of attached event handlers fails (I prefer to not throw exceptions) - then I will not change current page.

Comment: Just a tip: stop naming your events On... Name the event raisers like that. So the event is called PropertyChanged and the event raiser OnProperrtyChanged(...)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to know if any event handler failed to do his work you can either throw an Exception or provide a custom EventArgs type which tracks if any event handler failed.

```
public class FailureEventArgs : EventArgs // not the best name, I know
{
    private bool _failed;

    public bool Failed
    {
        get { return _failed; }
        set { _failed |= value; }
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
// Event declaration
public event EventHandler<FailureEventArgs> MyFailingEvent;

// Event invocation
private void Invoke()
{
    bool failure = false;
    var handler = MyFailingEvent;
    if (handler != null)
    {
        var args = new FailureEventArgs();
        handler(this, args);
        failure = args.Failed;
    }

    // more code, aware of possible failure
}

// In your event handler
private void OnEvent(object sender, FailureEventArgs args)
{
    var errorOccured = false;

    // some code which could set errorOccured to true

    args.Failure = errorOccured;
}
```

And, as already mentioned in my comment above, once the invokation of the event is over, you can be sure that there is no attached event handler processed anymore.

Comment: Thanks for answering. But I'm not sure, how I can check whether all methods that were bound (Using `EventTrigger` and `InvokeCommandAction` in XAML) return true (just for example).